# Why Output to JTextArea in real-time doesn't show up?

Tags: java, swing, console, jtextarea

I use JTextArea to show status of unzipping file.
But  for a reason it does not display the appended text.
**Can any one suggest a solution?**

```
public class UnzipFile extends Thread{
private static FtpTabPanel panel;
private File archive,outputDir;

public UnzipFile(File archive, File outputDir, FtpTabPanel panel) {
    UnzipFile.panel = panel;
    this.archive = archive;
    this.outputDir = outputDir;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();
    unzipArchive();
}

public void unzipArchive() {
    try {
        ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(archive);
        for (Enumeration e = zipfile.entries(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
            ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
            unzipEntry(zipfile, entry, outputDir);
        }
        panel.statusTextArea.append(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        OeExceptionDialog.show(e);
    }
}

private void unzipEntry(ZipFile zipfile, final ZipEntry entry, File outputDir)  {
    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
        createDir(new File(outputDir, entry.getName()));
        return;
    }

    File outputFile = new File(outputDir, entry.getName());
    if (!outputFile.getParentFile().exists()){
        createDir(outputFile.getParentFile());
    }

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            panel.statusTextArea.append("Extracting: " + entry + "\n");
        }
    });

    try {
    BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(zipfile.getInputStream(entry));
    BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();    
    }catch (IOException io){
        OeExceptionDialog.show(io);
    }catch (NullPointerException n){
        OeExceptionDialog.show(n);
    }catch (ArithmeticException a){
        OeExceptionDialog.show(a);
    }
}
}
```

**In the below code i use SwingWorkers but it unzip just one item from zip file and nothing appears in the jtextArea**

```
public class UnzipWorkers extends SwingWorker<String,Void> {
private WebTextArea statusTextArea;
private File archive,outputDir;

public UnzipWorkers(WebTextArea statusTextArea,File archive,File outputDir) {
    this.archive=archive;
    this.outputDir=outputDir;
    this.statusTextArea = statusTextArea;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
        statusTextArea.append(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        try {
            ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(archive);
            for (Enumeration e = zipfile.entries(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
                String status = unzipEntry(zipfile, entry, outputDir);
                return status;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            OeExceptionDialog.show(e);
        }

    return null;  
}

@Override
protected void done() {
    super.done();
    try {
        statusTextArea.append( get() + "\n");
        FileTreePanel.btnRefresh.doClick();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}

private String unzipEntry(ZipFile zipfile, final ZipEntry entry, File outputDir)  {
    String success = "Extracted failed: "+ entry + "\n";
    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
        createDir(new File(outputDir, entry.getName()));
    }

    File outputFile = new File(outputDir, entry.getName());
    if (!outputFile.getParentFile().exists()){
        createDir(outputFile.getParentFile());
    }
    try {
        BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(zipfile.getInputStream(entry));
        BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        success="Extracted successfully: " + entry + "\n";
    }catch (IOException io){
        OeExceptionDialog.show(io);
    }catch (NullPointerException n){
        OeExceptionDialog.show(n);
    }catch (ArithmeticException a){
        OeExceptionDialog.show(a);
    }
    return success;
}

private void createDir(File dir) {
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        try {
            dir.mkdirs();
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            OeExceptionDialog.show(re);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hmm to be honest I'm not sure what's causing this. Won't the text show even when the unzipping is done? If that's the case it might be thread related.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Use a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.
See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.  (Note: WAG based on title.)

Comment: May be model of statusTextArea is null?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by this line:

```
panel.statusTextArea.append(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

you are running your code on the EDT, otherwise you'd get an IllegalThreadAccess exception. So, in effect, your whole extraction procedure is done as the handling of a single event. Your requests to update the TextArea are just being pushed to the event queue and wait there until you have done "handling" the event that triggered the extraction code.

You must run your code on a dedicated thread (use SwingWorker).

Comment: What about this belock:` SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                panel.statusTextArea.append("Extracting: " + entry + "\n");

            }
        });´

Comment: Why doesn't show up anything in textArea? I have no explanation for it.

Comment: Since I gave the exact explanation in my answer, either you don't understand that, or I don't understand what you are doing. Let's try to sort this out. Do you know what is the EDT (Event-Dispatch Thread)?

Comment: Yes i do and there for i use SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). Is it correct way or do you means that i should impelements swingworkers?

Comment: I did update my code with new class but still has challenge to fix it.you can see in above code the changes.

Comment: Inside `doInBackground` you must use `invokeLater` around all code that updates the GUI, just like you had it before. Inside `done` you don't need that since `done` is executed on the EDT, as opposed to `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to move the

```
panel.statusTextArea.append(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

inside of the loop?

Comment: No, he's wrapping it in `unzipEntry()`; I think something else is blocking the EDT; it's probably `unzipEntry()` itself; an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) would be helpful.